# New Web Api methods not recognized only when web api is online

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, somee

I have a Web Api, I don't know why when I add new methods to it and I put my Web Api online the new methods are not recognized, if I run the application locally the methods are recognized, I'm using somee.com to upload and run my application online, for example if I just add this simple method:

```
[HttpGet]
[System.Web.Mvc.ValidateInput(false)]
public IHttpActionResult TestJustGet()
{
    var x = "new method tested";
    return Ok(x);
}
```

and I run the application locally it is recognized(http://localhost:62852/api/people/testjustget)
But when I try to call that method with the online application is not recognized(http://testwebhook.somee.com/api/people/testjustget) and I get this error:

```
<Error>
<Message>
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://testwebhook.somee.com/api/people/testjustget'.
</Message>
</Error>
```

I think that the problem is that the online application it's not recognizing the new changes, maybe I'm not updating it the best way. What I am doing to update my application is delete the old one that I have online, and instead upload the new application with the new methods added, but those methods are not being recognized, what can I do?

Comment: if in your local PC all works, then it`s clearly deploy issue. Probably new version of the Web API not transferred to the hosting server ...

Comment: I would validate that the newest version is actually getting deployed, then I would make sure that if you're adding new controllers that you make sure you are including the .csproj when you're 'deploying'. I'm not familiar with your deployment methods, though. Also, you could make sure that the server has all of the necessary nuget packages that your local version does? (just a shot in the dark)

Comment: I've tried different times and sometimes it recognizes the new methods and sometimes don't, I'm not sure why it behaves like that, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I need to run locally my application first and then upload it to somee.com, after I began to do that, it has recognized all the new methods, I run it locally and try all the new methods locally first and then I upload it and works